# How to check whether dhcp is enabled or not in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04

How to check whether dhcp is enabled or not  in ubuntu 12.04? Is there any command for that

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for command line only, you can check for the presents of the `dhclient` process, using the `ps` command

```
ps ax | grep dhclient
```

In 12.04 the network configuration should be written out to `/etc/network/interfaces` so you can check that file for lines similar to:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

The Ubuntu documentation on [networking](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/ubuntu-help/net.html) may help you out too.

Comment: This checks whether the service is running, not whether it is enabled.